# JavaScript disabled, with <noscript> tag can we do validations

Tags: javascript

I have a web form it contains some javascript validtions, but when user explicitly turned off Javascript in the browser, validations are not performed and data submitted by the user gets wrong.

My first concern is that how to prevent  the user to submit the form.

I have googled and I got that **noscript** tag can be used to tell the user that Javascript is disabled in your browser. What I want to ask is that when the user has disabled the Javascript in the browser, can we do any client side validation so user will not submit wrong data.

And can I write code to disable the submit button like

`document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true` Is this possible.

Any help or suggestion would a great help for me.

Comment: you can use `<noscript>` tag to inform user to enable the browser's javascript and refresh your page to view it properly.

Comment: Never trust the client! Always do server-side validation, even if it duplicates code used in the client.

Answer (score 3):

If JavaScript is disabled none of your client side validations will work fine. Also your code to disable the button also will not work because it is javascript :(

You can try something like this to hide your form if JavaScript is disabled and show the message to the user.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<noscript>JavaScript is disabled. </noscript>
  <form method="POST" action="http://www.google.com" id="my-form" class="hidden">
     <input type="text" value="Some text here" />

     <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
  </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("my-form").style.display = "block";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

​
OR you can do any of these method to redirect the user to another page.

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=your-noscript-page.html">
</noscript>
```

OR this

```
<noscript>
  <a href="your-noscript-page.html">JavaScript is disabled in your browser. Click here to continue</a>
</noscript>
```

OR the Modernizr method without using the Modernizr library.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.no-js form {
    display:none;
}
.js-disabled {
    display:none;
}
.no-js .js-disabled {
    display:block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body class="no-js">
<div class="js-disabled">JavaScript is disabled in your browser.</div>
<form method="POST" action="http://www.google.com" id="my-form">
    <input type="text" value="Some text here" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className = "";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** no. **Long answer:** you should always validate on the server, even if you've already (or so you think) validated on the client end. It's always safest to expect that all of your users are malicious, and treat the "nice" user as the exception.